# Convex hull in the $L^{p}$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $L^{p}$, with $p>2$, be the Banach space of the functions $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $p$-th integrable power, endowed its usual norm. I am looking for a sequence $(f_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ in the closed unit ball of $L^{p}$ (if exists) obeying the following conditions:

(a) $\|f_{n}-f_{m}\|=r$ for all $n\neq m$, for some $r>0$.

(b) $a:=\inf\{ \|f\|:f\in \mathrm{cConv}(f_{n}:n\geq 1) \}>0$, where "cConv" stands for the closed convex hull.

I have tried with the Rademacher system, $f_{n}(x):=\mathrm{sign}\sin(2^{n}\pi x)$, but it seems that this sequence does not satisfy the above conditions becasuse of $a=0$.

Some suggestion?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: If you take sign-changing sequences, such as the Rademacher system, there is a bigger chance that the origin will fall into the convex hull. On the other hand, if you can find a sequence of positive functions that is uniformly bounded below, then the origin will be automatically out of the way. However, I don't know if the condition (a) can be satisfied under so powerful an assumption.

Comment: Oh, also, don't forget Mazur's lemma: if $f_n \rightharpoonup 0$, then (b) won't be satisfied. So $f_n$ must be chosen in such a way that no subsequences of it weakly converge to 0. Notice that $f_n$ is bounded, so it always have subsequences that weakly converge to something. Thus, the only way out is to take a sequence $f_n$ such that $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ for some $f\ne 0$. **This comment is much more important than my previous one**.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @GiuseppeNegro  I forgot the condition $p>2$, but your comments are interesting.

Comment: What if you took the $f_n$ to satisfy  a) with each $f_n$ supported on $[0,1/2]$ and of norm less than 1/2, and then set $g_n=f_n+b\chi_{[1/2,1]}$ for some well-chosen $b$?

Comment: Thanks for your commet, @David Mitra.  I will try to find such a sequence.

Comment: Hi, I recalled this interesting question. Did you find an example in the end?